# C# UWP TCP Client

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to make a TCP Client in a UWP application.
I can create a client with no issues. The problem is I need to listen continuously to anything that remote device sends back such as a login prompt.
I did try to use Stream Socket also but that listens for incoming only.
The goal is to open a connection and send and receive to that remote device only for the connection.
I have tried many options I have found online with no luck.

Basics of the connection:

1. Connect to the remote device and stay connected.
2. Wait for prompts(which can be slow at times).
3. Send back login in information
4. Get logged in confirmation
5. Stay connected and send and receive data continuously.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is,  sockets _are_ bi-directional.   Maybe post your code?  [MCVE]

Comment: I was able to get it working.   I will post my solution later today when I am at my laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working properly with this:

```
   private TcpClient client;
    private NetworkStream recieveData;
    private Task rx;

    public delegate void DataRecived(string data);
    public event DataRecived OnDataRecived;

    public delegate void ConnectionStatus(bool data);
    public event ConnectionStatus clientConnected;

    public delegate void LogStatus(bool data);
    public event LogStatus loggedIn;

    public delegate void ValueChanged(int value);
    public event ValueChanged newLightValue;

    public string Ip;
    public int Port;

    private bool auth;
    public bool valueInChanging;
 public Client()
    {
       client = new TcpClient();
       rx = new Task(StartReading);
    }
    public async void Connect()
    {
        try
        {
            await client.ConnectAsync(Ip, Port);
            clientConnected(client.Connected);
            rx.Start();                                  
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OnDataRecived("Error Connecting" + ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void StartReading()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            recieveData = client.GetStream();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            Byte[] data = new Byte[256];
            string responseData;
            if (recieveData != null)
            {
                int bytesRead = recieveData.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
                if (!auth)
                {
                    OnReceivedMessage(responseData);
                }
                else
                {
                    Feedback(responseData);
                }
            }
        }           
    }
```